# How to stay current screen without going to top(looks like refresh)

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.mail

I used the System.Net.Mail. I have two problems.

First, after I submit, the lblMessage.Text is showing and the page goes to the top. So what I want is when I submit, the page stay in my submit button.

Second, after I submit, the data still there, and if refresh page, it will re-submit again.

How to figure out those two problems. Thanks.

```
   public partial class Contact : Page
    {
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
                msg.To.Add("xxx@hotmail.com");
                msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                msg.Body = "<h1>" + txtName.Text + " <br />" + "<h3> Phone Number: " + txtPhone.Text + "<br />" + "Email Address: " + txtEmail.Text + "<br />" + "Message: <br />" + txtMessage.Text + ".<br />";
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                /*
                Sl.No   Mail Server SMTP Server( Host ) Port Number
                1   Gmail   smtp.gmail.com  587
                2   Outlook smtp.live.com   587
                3   Yahoo Mail  smtp.mail.yahoo.com 465
                4   Yahoo Mail Plus plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com    465
                5   Hotmail smtp.live.com   465
                6   Office365.com   smtp.office365.com  587
                7   zoho Mail   smtp.zoho.com   465
               */
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
                NetworkCred.Password = "BLACKroseFh521";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(msg);
                lblMessage.Text = "Email has been successfully sent! <br />We will be in touch soon.";
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: For the first you can set `maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack` to true or use `UpdatePanel`. The second is just part of the webform life, due to the nature of webforms F5 will always resubmit the data. A quick fix would be to do a repsonse.redirect but it's better to make sure that pressing F5 is handled correctly.

Comment: Hi Mason, Thanks. But I am a newbie. Could you please type it?

Comment: <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Title="Contact" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="XinNing_Web.Contact" %> Do you mean like this?

Comment: It is refreshing and jumping to what I stayed